# Smart Phone's camera socket

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, cellphone, socket

I just want ask how the socket in the image is called?

I couldn't really find and the closer I could get is only Raspberry's module.

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find the socket, there is something stuck in it...

Comment: @PlasmaHH I've found better picture.

Comment: Maybe somebody can help you if you tell us the make and model of the smartphone. Or you search for "<smartphone name> teardown" to find a better image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This closely resembles a SlimStack Mezzanine connector from Molex:

[image]

Such connectors are often used to connect two PCBs, or a PCB and a flex support. I have seen them in virtually all mobile phones, cameras and even in some MP3 players I have taken apart. They are commonly used to connect IO peripherals like cameras, LCD displays or [keyboards](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/how-to-connect-to-a-very-very-challanging-blackberry-q10-keyboard-connector/). I know about a project where [CPU+RAM module](https://pyra-handheld.com/boards/ubergall/gallery-images/CPU-Board-Prototype.JPG) is connected in this way to make it upgradable.