# What is this flex pcb connector called?

Tags: connector, identification

I'd like to use this connector in my design but couldn't find what it's called. Anyone know?

[image]

Comment: See if [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236085/smart-phones-camera-socket) answers your question. Looks like another incarnation of SlimStack.

Comment: samtec connector?

Answer (score 0):

It is a PCB Connector Extended Flex Cable Ribbon
http://www.etradesupply.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?sku=ESAPP13072610211

Comment: That name appears to be a description of the cable assembly, not a specific name for the connector.